# Detect installed certificate on iOS 11 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

I have iOS 11 and this code doesn't detect my installed custom certificate:

```
- (BOOL)IsMobileConfigInstalled {
    NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
    SecCertificateRef cert = NULL;
    if ([certData length]) {
         cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certData);
        if (cert != NULL) {
            CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(cert);
            NSString *summaryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(__bridge NSString *) certSummary];
            CFRelease(certSummary);
        }
    }
    SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecTrustRef trust;
    OSStatus err = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFArrayRef) @[
            (__bridge id) cert
    ], policy, &trust);
    SecTrustResultType trustResult = (SecTrustResultType) -1;
    err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
    CFRelease(trust);
    CFRelease(policy);
    CFRelease(cert);
    return kSecTrustResultUnspecified == trustResult;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't explain what it is supposed to do and what it does instead. The other problem is that you should try this on iOS 10 first.

Comment: @deadbeef of course in ios 10 it is working. And already released this app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Apple just "fixed" result in trustResult.

So, now corrent answer: kSecTrustResultProceed

My fixed code version:
Work on ios 10 and 11.

```
- (BOOL)IsMobileConfigInstalled {
    NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
    SecCertificateRef cert = NULL;
    if ([certData length]) {
        cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certData);
        if (cert != NULL) {
            CFStringRef certSummary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(cert);
            NSString *summaryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:(__bridge NSString *) certSummary];
            CFRelease(certSummary);
        }
    }
    SecPolicyRef policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecTrustRef trust;
    OSStatus err = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFArrayRef) @[
            (__bridge id) cert
    ], policy, &trust);
    SecTrustResultType trustResult = (SecTrustResultType) -1;
    err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
    CFRelease(trust);
    CFRelease(policy);
    CFRelease(cert);
    NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    float ver_float = [ver floatValue];
    if (ver_float >= 11)
        return kSecTrustResultProceed == trustResult;
    return kSecTrustResultUnspecified == trustResult;
}
```